# How do I read x bytes from a stream?

Tags: java, sockets, io, stream

I want to read exactly *n* bytes from a Socket at a time. How can I achieve that?

Comment: For characters you can use the higher level construction java.io.Reader to read exactly n characters, is there maybe something like this for bytes?

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone. :) I took the solution of Michael and it works. The one of Mark is also nice. Again, thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`DataInputStream.readFully()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Of course it may block for an arbitrarily long time...

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally just reimplemented this.  Thanks for the link.  Didn't think `DataInputStream` played nice in this case.

Comment: If you don't want arbitrary blocks, check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16293601/83741

Answer (score 5):

You can create a helper method to completely fill a buffer.  Something like this:

```
public int fillBufferCompletely(InputStream is, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    int size = bytes.length;
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < size) {
        int read = is.read(bytes, offset, size - offset);
        if (read == -1) {
            if ( offset == 0 ) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return offset;
            }
        } else {
            offset += read;
        }
    }

    return size;
}
```

Then you just need to pass in a buffer of size `x`.

### Edit

Michael posted a link to a function which does essentially the same thing.  The only difference with mine is that it does have the ability to return less than the buffer length, but only on the condition of an end-of-stream.  `DataInputStream.readFully` would throw a runtime exception in this scenario.

So I'll leave my answer up in case an example of that behaviour is useful.

Comment: Also thank you for your post Mark Peters. You're one is also really good. :)
PS: sorry that I can't give +1 to you and Michael, my reputation is too low :p

Answer (score 3):

[DataInputStream.readFully()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D%29) throws an exception on EOF, as Mark Peters points out. But there are two other methods who don't: Commons IO's [IOUtils.read()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,%20byte%5B%5D%29) and Guavas [ByteStreams.read()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29). These both try to read up to N bytes, stopping only at EOF, and return how many they actually read.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. The underlying platforms cannot guarantee this, so neither can Java. You can attempt to read *n* bytes, but you always have to be prepared that you get less than what was requested.

Comment: So what method would be used for reading (up to) *n* bytes? How can this be used in such a method as to keep trying until all the requested bytes are read?

Comment: @MarkPeters posted some useful code. Though I don't think the OP wanted what we thought he did, based off his response to Michael :)

Comment: @Perception: Actually reading the docs for `readFully` it looks like that method is almost exactly what I posted (with some differences in the corner cases).

Comment: This is not impossible. You just write the code or call readFully(). Downvoted.

Comment: Well quite obviously you can write code to do it, the OP's questions seems very much framed as looking for a single call that reads exactly x number of bytes. What a frivolous down vote.